# how to make perfect media player in android with url type source

Tags: java, android

I have created a media player which get data from **url**. **Url** is based on volley response. I'm creating a `MediaPlayer` on item click so the `onItemClick` create every time a new `MediaPlayer()` . so i declared it in `onCreate()` but after it's giving too much errors .
below my code with `MediaPlayer()` declaration in `onItemClick` please help me anyone thanks

**my motive:- i want to stop the playing song when another song is playing on item click**

```
public class MusicsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
}

   public void OnItemClickActivity(int position,String video,String thumbnail,String thumbnails) {
    String webUrl = "https://musicexample.com/";
    Glide.with(this).load(webUrl + image).into(image);
    text.setText(text);
    Atext.setText(Atext);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying() && mMediaPlayer != null)
    {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.reset();;
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            togglePlayPause();
        }
    });
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(webUrl + src);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post errors and logs as well.

Comment: still no errors but mediaplayer not release when i am clicked another song. Together playing multiples songs how can i remove this?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the Media Player without the risk of an Illegal State Exception, you must do

```
  try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.prepare();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
       }
  catch (Exception e)
         {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
```